# Application crashes with UITextViewDelegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface-builder, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

I'm new to iPhone programming and Objective-C and am having some trouble with my `UITextView`. I have a view with a text view as its subview. I created a separate class which I want to be the delgate of the text view. In my header for this delegate class, I have the statement:

```
@interface MessageTextViewDelegate : NSObject UITextViewDelegate
```

with angle brackets around `UITextViewDelegate`. I also connected the text view in interface builder to my delegate class, which I created as an object in interface builder. When I run my application, however, and click on the text view, the application crashes.

The same thing happens when I try to initialize an instance of the text view delegate in code and set my text view's delegate to be that instance. When I don't have the delegate in my application (i.e. it is not connected in interface builder or it is not typed out in code), the application runs. I need the delegate though so that I can perform an animated resize on the text view when the keyboard shows up. 

Could you please help me either with the code or with what I should do in Interface Builder to make the application function with the delegate?

**@willcodejavaforfood**

I get the following error message when I tap the textView field:

> [Session started at 2010-08-29 17:39:50 -0400.]
>   Loading program into debugger…
>   GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-962) (Sat Jul 26 08:14:40 UTC 2008)
>   Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
>   GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
>   welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
>   Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
>   There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
>   This GDB was configured as "i386-apple-darwin".warning: Unable to read symbols for "/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit" (file not found).
>   warning: Unable to read symbols from "UIKit" (not yet mapped into memory).
>   warning: Unable to read symbols for "/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics" (file not found).
>   warning: Unable to read symbols from "CoreGraphics" (not yet mapped into memory).
>   Program loaded.
>   sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
>   Attaching to program: `/Users/vivek/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications/86E8C2CB-3CB7-4615-BF2F-82F3B8982EB3/TestApp.app/TestApp', process 1493.
>   kill
>   error while killing target (killing anyway): warning: error on line 1987 of "/SourceCache/gdb/gdb-962/src/gdb/macosx/macosx-nat-inferior.c" in function "macosx_kill_inferior_safe": (os/kern) failure (0x5x)
>   quit

The Debugger has exited with status 0.

Comment: Crashes with what error message?

Comment: Hi, willcodejavaforfood, I just edited my question to include the error. Could you please take a look above?

Answer (score 0):

You would normally connect the UITextView in IB with a property in your MessageTextViewDelegate class of type UITextView.  That is create the following in your code:

```
@interface MessageTextViewDelegate

     UITextView *myTextView;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *myTextView;

@implementation MessageTextViewDelegate

@synthesize myTextView
```

You then connected your text view object in IB with the myTextView property.

Comment: Hi ennuikiller, I tried doing this but my application still crashes. Do I need to initialize an instance of the delegate somewhere in my code also?

Answer (score 0):

based on the errors that are generated, it looks like your project is is not compiling the application correctly. I would start with "cleaning" all targets and do an complete recompile.

Answer (score 0):

If I am correctly understanding your problem then its:

If you have a ViewController "A" and it has a subview with textview "B"...

To solve your problem, 
make ViewController "A" your TextViewDelegate. You can then handle things.

Cheers,

Kunjal